# How to solve "system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.12737e-31" error message when using plm package

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to fit a `pcce` model using the `plm` package, but I end up with this error message, `**Error in solve.default(crossprod(tHhat), t(tHhat)): system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.12737e-31**`, which I've have tried solutions provided to similar errors on this platform and elsewhere but to no avail.

Below is the `reprex` for my data and the codes needed to reproduce the error as well as my `R` session information.

```r
library(reprex)
library(plm)


AT <- structure(list(country = c("Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore"), ccode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L), .Label = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), rgg = c(0.7, 
11.1, 13.4, 8.5, 2.3, 3.8, 5.7, 6.2, 6.2, 6, 2.4, 4.3, 5.1, -5.9, 
2.5, 7.7, 0.6, 1.7, 3.1, 8.7, 7.4, 7, 6.5, 2.1, -2.5, 6.8, 4.8, 
1.7, 3.1, 2.8, 2.4, 2.2, 3.8, 7.7, 11.2, 12.5, 11.9, 7, 9.8, 
10.4, 6.2, 6.8, 9.2, 9.6, 7.6, 5.9, -5.5, 11.3, 8.4, 4.9, 7.7, 
3.1, 5.2, 4.3, 5.3, 5.8, 3, 0.8, 6.8, 3.7, 2.4, 3.2, 3.2, 2.8, 
2.9, 3.2, -0.6, 1.3, 10.8, 11.3, 10.2, 9.8, 6.7, 6.6, 11.5, 11.1, 
7.2, 7.5, 8.3, -2.2, 5.7, 9, -1.1, 3.9, 4.5, 9.8, 7.4, 9, 9, 
1.9, 0.1, 14.5, 6.3, 4.4, 4.8, 3.9, 2.9, 3, 3.7), hdi = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.781, 0.786, 0.791, 0.799, 0.804, 0.808, 0.811, 
0.816, 0.817, 0.821, 0.827, 0.835, 0.842, 0.851, 0.862, 0.871, 
0.883, 0.887, 0.896, 0.898, 0.901, 0.904, 0.911, 0.915, 0.923, 
0.927, 0.93, 0.933, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.728, 0.739, 0.746, 
0.756, 0.767, 0.778, 0.789, 0.8, 0.797, 0.808, 0.817, 0.824, 
0.832, 0.839, 0.847, 0.855, 0.862, 0.869, 0.874, 0.869, 0.884, 
0.888, 0.89, 0.893, 0.896, 0.898, 0.9, 0.903, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.718, 0.729, 0.74, 0.751, 0.763, 0.773, 0.782, 0.793, 0.798, 
0.809, 0.819, 0.822, 0.83, 0.838, 0.845, 0.868, 0.871, 0.878, 
0.883, 0.884, 0.909, 0.914, 0.92, 0.923, 0.928, 0.929, 0.93, 
0.932), ineq = c(38.5, 38.5, 38.7, 38.8, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 39.4, 
39.5, 39.7, 39.8, 39.9, 40, 40.1, 40.2, 40.3, 40.3, 40.4, 40.5, 
40.6, 40.6, 40.7, 40.7, 40.8, 40.9, 40.9, 40.9, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
41, 41, 30.6, 30.5, 30.3, 30.1, 29.9, 29.5, 29.1, 28.8, 28.8, 
28.9, 29.1, 29.5, 29.9, 30.5, 30.8, 30.7, 30.9, 30.8, 30.7, 30.8, 
30.9, 30.9, 31.3, 31.4, 31.5, 31.2, 31.2, 31, 31.1, 31.3, 31.7, 
32.3, 32.7, 37.1, 37.2, 37.3, 37.4, 37.6, 37.8, 38, 38.2, 38.3, 
38.4, 38.5, 38.6, 38.7, 38.8, 38.8, 38.9, 39, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 
39.3, 39.4, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.3, 39.2, 39, 38.8, 38.7, 
38.6, 38.6), emp = c(96.5779467680608, 97.037037037037, 98.1684981684982, 
98.9130434782609, 98.9090909090909, 98.5454545454545, 98.2142857142857, 
98.2078853046595, 97.9020979020979, 97.9522184300341, 97, 97.1518987341772, 
97.8328173374613, 95.1219512195122, 93.6746987951807, 95.0536423448521, 
94.9114463280133, 92.679836433796, 92.0595533498759, 93.1877704395354, 
94.4089185671439, 95.2124979002184, 95.9859757612567, 96.4780600461894, 
94.7354042018414, 95.6709718282709, 96.5785423023953, 96.7161969224261, 
96.5993100049285, 96.703779287541, 96.6847714695634, 96.6072294074131, 
96.8732579942229, 96.0107747562853, 96.2087366592206, 96.92407989095, 
97.4861303744799, 97.4310603118238, 97.5511084740277, 97.7086058069579, 
97.6101338530181, 97.2282307963177, 97.5926652284762, 97.9811058360907, 
97.9946335263381, 97.4332933247161, 93.1860551826995, 93.7459554405103, 
95.5848494424631, 96.0152814179734, 96.7365764511357, 96.4370958642538, 
96.3387699626232, 96.2602243022177, 96.5201465201465, 96.7557800501006, 
96.839232617816, 96.3631925799365, 96.3014906234974, 96.6048288628934, 
96.7960901439044, 96.901332924774, 96.5009688478164, 96.4092365484477, 
96.3199358085929, 96.3132478016434, 95.8850931677019, 93.5334872979215, 
95.3348382242287, 96.7343976777939, 97.8245614035088, 98.3365323096609, 
98.0694980694981, 97.2839506172839, 97.3105134474328, 97.4010632014176, 
97.3127501429388, 97.0033296337403, 97.5479744136461, 96.7908902691511, 
95.4453441295547, 95.5748175182482, 96.5566037735849, 95.8028096182022, 
95.4936643169139, 95.5677014390025, 95.7544778641433, 96.5961219690837, 
97.1073312917389, 97.2175924351168, 95.9042904290429, 97.1714659268471, 
97.300052516141, 97.4091260634184, 97.3633011005604, 97.4340092896794, 
97.3799368526007, 97.201045523851, 97.076838939021), total = c(15.9202011096209, 
15.2642825978261, 13.8835753131415, 14.171521799986, 15.5469757911512, 
16.2006058337021, 15.9486863729186, 15.6059692740854, 17.0032284957751, 
16.1152020882272, 17.4536584742895, 17.4451762082705, 17.4616562021679, 
20.8186896901981, 21.6256036670214, 20.6063397335778, 20.4113562357415, 
20.5390063213912, 21.9111794752636, 19.9850563689254, 17.8123041515447, 
16.2881456160271, 15.2956584740567, 19.3831636785522, 18.5139928099829, 
18.0467390105003, 19.9356916507705, 19.6449391009293, 21.3882491038463, 
18.7657106953303, 19.515152525977, 19.8665196131373, 19.2677668365412, 
18.2838941361669, 16.7893360882124, 16.3493048436123, 15.8058314157684, 
17.3263966207143, 18.6222923203409, 18.6186845010184, 18.3122914122914, 
17.6746775640818, 18.5912487979543, 17.3210812243275, 18.3435250036441, 
20.4010801366055, 23.716320068772, 24.4802421159041, 19.4569224706369, 
20.2065482327053, 16.700663008306, 18.7523959085942, 18.529429377332, 
19.1724499236407, 19.942014804075, 18.7129529003629, 20.4577737365564, 
22.3441750459224, 18.9894052008633, 19.4864821822038, 20.0737248521191, 
19.7596765659499, 19.7692934080367, 20.2798469789636, 20.194744929226, 
20.1219895514415, 27.1840918725192, 29.2487692602775, 35.2956131835622, 
23.0338268873143, 22.3296755684575, 21.2650165583954, 21.3984158256604, 
19.5236899256874, 17.3444918988687, 13.9627690399078, 16.1672524244994, 
21.0982307785774, 16.7726977165494, 20.0459861341301, 19.0335889849647, 
19.1001660112035, 22.2476498614084, 18.859896102842, 18.630695181316, 
17.1356363728505, 14.7367573960416, 14.7642415560525, 13.8119800114872, 
16.6962801905864, 17.9157516410459, 14.505162068252, 14.6621876204514, 
14.2683860818447, 13.9857107463955, 14.6498327225184, 17.4691299276575, 
16.3177514024186, 16.1987329487883), hea = c(1.35331237219938, 
1.39012296139184, 1.28880456193846, 1.24068339281965, 1.37626166805798, 
1.57074299717504, 1.57889219147519, 1.72319886164745, 2.02200022129493, 
1.87633585265879, 2.21525309163951, 2.0779982244978, 2.08114858100801, 
2.45341250927843, 2.55943582311373, 2.44635331113771, 2.58730704193796, 
2.55669095480679, 2.72155993344309, 2.4449693951702, 2.23889528193326, 
2.13702588417475, 2.03682433987821, 2.14970889968708, 2.31352211397352, 
2.24563876572623, 2.34162001209659, 2.92441210588402, 3.16147602891075, 
2.54459614027403, 2.93643778040929, 2.66888504972291, 2.67698064963211, 
0.236004525777253, 0.244882039172693, 0.360438137376572, 0.327146663437084, 
0.320654264256361, 0.318014284356002, 0.330791507128968, 0.172120472120472, 
0.157947653488146, 0.113293775335722, 0.135709553464953, 0.162971140726297, 
0.171440799865865, 0.215430038684241, 0.218003745256285, 0.144252666832813, 
0.118242547996786, 0.0634604040847602, 0.183671397777552, 0.172493657253012, 
0.21954199487429, 0.217034282466762, 0.182249475570458, 0.189652461215032, 
0.234040352007972, 0.224707003842097, 0.190145385982894, 0.181722052891186, 
0.203688772351045, 0.193738819469011, 0.285099025319592, 0.246498752627846, 
0.242142199627368, 1.75729315195191, 1.18662489610639, 1.26658346045394, 
1.19269006536255, 1.04369737883831, 0.974814792664967, 1.33220752415799, 
1.1868354829337, 1.03829384670371, 1.01992469246953, 1.23231903781605, 
1.16968868285825, 1.12679317908881, 1.43560774061019, 1.27016256195849, 
0.978438835207565, 1.22710279451947, 1.05393723556448, 1.47056629854858, 
0.98600967942016, 0.857428757968938, 0.847036325559884, 0.834413768201352, 
1.02705000412387, 1.38266371458401, 1.17911249217105, 1.15633305279144, 
1.3051547956642, 1.53992474358164, 1.77338945762091, 2.1104556658128, 
2.23389203660304, 2.18195591534874), edu = c(2.65312254934295, 
2.74330336527591, 2.45103241554434, 2.55310028693401, 2.54534416027927, 
2.81984956264252, 2.87325008453341, 2.80291513283518, 2.78634413113806, 
2.80692929412599, 3.06860671207548, 3.13049941160683, 3.49761183328796, 
3.7878657655194, 4.03704577517346, 3.90369801592672, 4.01554110004829, 
4.28530355550314, 4.55895705233439, 4.13463239654687, 3.84279012127113, 
3.4545492037455, 3.26062725199848, 4.39212714357415, 3.51003016432172, 
3.41822362035926, 3.509612650755, 3.76032309324374, 3.57254928553223, 
3.26211667673302, 3.29269309671931, 3.3097482919481, 3.32610166994678, 
3.02821231798505, 2.85941683708967, 2.80014029029299, 2.79747486980744, 
2.97050547581935, 3.15933712534327, 2.59053812508371, 2.64220594220594, 
3.47574928737968, 3.3925363396587, 3.38288061481383, 3.44946819314709, 
3.58474748276988, 3.76492853879789, 3.66430240458711, 2.97298607931073, 
3.24234927575732, 2.7490588299609, 2.87150764600861, 2.81581860404086, 
2.87127924885304, 2.8407475525842, 2.79010832918372, 3.100804745037, 
3.22678676036798, 2.84860736095385, 2.95103335125591, 3.13121609897679, 
3.2157773045399, 3.21895640934146, 3.03928709200442, 3.08758213848554, 
3.17007447084711, 5.86792040797975, 5.30912345757944, 5.09406924605926, 
4.37646634181556, 4.03347323077971, 4.22818440744866, 4.89861016176806, 
4.34844701838364, 4.29210949704791, 3.16083934238965, 3.05389840681155, 
3.1391644992948, 3.15728013589295, 3.64737738976167, 3.80613781408793, 
4.01584779220318, 4.32510990329825, 4.40852687222882, 4.0866328879784, 
3.70111677990171, 3.18494067694719, 2.94340792680498, 2.87517282280681, 
3.11361852631013, 3.28434196157492, 3.04906516325946, 3.05526001613958, 
2.90699840616009, 3.0711239520434, 2.9243668158173, 2.86309338115704, 
2.88010695969337, 2.79654316073746), soc = c(0.923462544798927, 
0.818787201314646, 0.739528948274389, 0.760856253061796, 0.829285876906731, 
0.903475034886491, 0.93643825664787, 0.922384019592604, 1.00459132195235, 
1.06314692655566, 1.29047500462936, 1.48159464871895, 1.61467142068773, 
2.06094464195023, 2.21613405941897, 2.07304517903164, 2.24169695611827, 
2.45270904103085, 2.65248844365541, 2.52743272518526, 2.35545720102682, 
2.23101591045604, 2.11224432926489, 2.29858265392357, 2.43592718374924, 
2.28104881294713, 2.24076342902043, 2.25295389087896, 2.58859236638365, 
2.57039254337933, 2.70581416681955, 2.73621543797073, 2.66254989227665, 
0.958038173947265, 1.02011342792688, 1.01881328800878, 1.13880646723992, 
1.38093213762762, 1.50517066841166, 1.58800245714998, 1.6958485958486, 
1.64931512773111, 1.83412851298828, 1.68588843248973, 1.88401329576872, 
2.12484225946223, 2.75724795045537, 3.04581724475084, 2.96838227079479, 
2.60450427731102, 2.70547758860149, 3.10891904963785, 3.27605854084676, 
3.44516954344665, 3.67620772244274, 3.81789662502127, 4.12816832890537, 
4.47986916970099, 4.2605113278944, 4.32755347038009, 4.59089484327393, 
4.85108431789014, 5.0671530867463, 5.28346937106443, 5.31905360104174, 
5.40600846043211, 0.429046719847907, 0.465443385972764, 0.453011602644109, 
0.462952064844676, 0.480134846382388, 0.448534413802899, 0.461045662284052, 
0.449372356090042, 0.66391414508327, 0.399625038594878, 0.802772633775124, 
2.22479247830962, 0.300054574632045, 0.147354046546371, 0.29941617470825, 
0.677868512532007, 2.76328292742272, 0.787599305999452, 0.402758648123194, 
0.554699300098381, 0.299860560049472, 1.19087417959595, 0.562387396236158, 
2.04738238467426, 2.23806266575464, 1.12141322262519, 1.57267069626841, 
1.7475661167574, 1.4740866149498, 1.59293982998783, 1.8452730832712, 
1.44852649425049, 0.998468881705865), hou = c(3.33948975029866, 
2.96559565096926, 2.84499918462857, 3.14730736930506, 3.37956287470593, 
3.52217419420714, 3.19838995226262, 2.86913368692019, 3.03009720543947, 
3.19254826063608, 3.16976856830888, 3.52614736668249, 3.32350101818755, 
4.62249482361214, 5.31283152534158, 4.56164144924004, 3.79769926321319, 
3.26837354249962, 3.42444987502676, 2.66631433715353, 2.26594671151633, 
2.10343426119383, 1.99672150214811, 3.92248960021365, 2.56354546796887, 
2.58876156033895, 3.16615230326246, 2.46512251240637, 3.32291230671022, 
2.5053484394946, 2.56934136130894, 2.51069677918242, 2.62512011538593, 
0.883633412042503, 0.825936623727098, 0.964315904962319, 0.767152113358363, 
1.49564431128835, 1.98208023624557, 1.81002350919815, 1.41599511599512, 
1.19907602604713, 1.32616177139023, 1.50801643036968, 1.69121987005322, 
1.47298776021673, 1.65077514756946, 2.17322224615946, 1.03938650261558, 
1.72545013848946, 0.316410006711766, 1.03813749081942, 1.28759304970547, 
1.43591117970087, 1.45231485832111, 1.31636449601445, 1.21840226681909, 
1.40747769295117, 0.932246755509102, 0.918544049363787, 1.10019266565073, 
0.846537733961408, 0.861459532804083, 0.864102757722402, 0.819862548940716, 
1.64150076521293, 1.13042249540766, 4.18899047375487, 3.42763370776129, 
2.72082421160833, 2.12655469195604, 1.30074980002841, 1.08292120676022, 
1.30625772551105, 1.2122266259268, 0.921641040286098, 1.31553839985138, 
1.58880790189688, 1.51580510996471, 2.42550596419151, 2.56424941874838, 
2.05009251732084, 2.33386271047674, 2.02860723018699, 2.69562385325663, 
2.26672057587372, 1.7742548153726, 1.56242692362989, 1.68304624635412, 
1.22036828251638, 1.21053389494906, 1.31281348773162, 1.25998438012031, 
0.998806345000793, 0.773135293652596, 0.90881541173672, 0.801687873322594, 
1.01291891058634, 1.17931417456033), eco = c(3.0019861773781, 
2.99744268330356, 2.75233157402925, 2.75233571278606, 3.48448053426425, 
2.96041659575916, 3.00732229157161, 3.2050285662293, 3.93357208353555, 
3.30150431211539, 3.29282298134663, 2.85294299812127, 2.92916716869486, 
3.61136070633277, 2.92889849727236, 3.68126827568727, 3.39123273652643, 
3.76770640872369, 4.18813545969543, 4.08618708849014, 3.56569000619634, 
2.94601859445998, 2.53520205287759, 3.27738952038873, 4.05497681174269, 
3.80418750548884, 5.23590928593953, 4.78223752969354, 5.27123118544829, 
4.2708755069126, 4.26042830695332, 4.8497552698977, 4.17898197771275, 
3.99805686737505, 3.04178701692986, 2.88863109048724, 3.06883553348674, 
3.27543742450927, 3.79704357455662, 3.84867281569989, 3.43015873015873, 
3.51171364014746, 4.18073820294551, 4.68429839671393, 5.24874605416281, 
5.3683407019123, 6.8063109996917, 6.73385893972789, 4.90366991061245, 
5.91116561834841, 3.77500202933119, 3.5697694553749, 3.42378444259121, 
3.57408518772512, 3.59770744176495, 3.45100243176726, 3.81055027371381, 
4.51579241408931, 3.59947050198879, 3.49519042329632, 3.38883505817675, 
3.25882046677045, 3.04185302351246, 3.35158723016918, 3.17265896268545, 
2.54197558182494, 4.80686474751757, 5.81037018093472, 5.50778902602505, 
3.68399990584026, 4.45571947866209, 3.57182904858375, 2.29718681731066, 
2.25301756615007, 1.99386356670375, 1.24616253334458, 1.66186544185699, 
3.05918578593697, 2.87981790570379, 3.86986741053713, 2.45767755995392, 
3.83258867141576, 3.36105165208413, 2.31840826307085, 1.98706697229916, 
2.07337454376396, 1.70671433778957, 1.57065478159801, 1.35451921116094, 
2.07798489206458, 2.92208181829091, 2.12835853953842, 2.26329458198055, 
1.92392346808525, 1.60523405190318, 1.71887106060716, 3.74753125619179, 
2.66953165811053, 2.85793126766109), gen = c(2.28886787889448, 
1.97515294537279, 1.71279770764145, 1.61815907341312, 1.74186081809213, 
2.06817330928151, 2.15460533601478, 2.02522623619552, 2.32896476699945, 
2.03209833623527, 2.42232019141392, 2.36496892871152, 2.24811943957291, 
2.32027190686409, 2.49427429152884, 1.94085836197506, 2.29225927265956, 
2.12180143848071, 2.247608558817, 2.18611350933104, 1.78787288660706, 
1.74503492531019, 1.65875514006916, 1.70338046497572, 1.8374019508873, 
1.87493103766638, 1.81211002724317, 1.79390974930034, 1.82097502461061, 
1.89088077238767, 1.95298297112931, 2.05829438515953, 2.06754421204495, 
1.72262396694215, 1.68391979928739, 1.53114264645048, 1.42659258810706, 
1.53552366107276, 1.57938891592141, 1.64559768325859, 1.78962148962149, 
1.68863086808146, 1.77652308082385, 1.84245395521399, 1.87510006475833, 
1.9940389519851, 2.33471432397095, 2.12126924415425, 1.02097126855181, 
0.970409236609986, 1.04926298641348, 1.10262549784144, 0.890868645914883, 
0.87451242772713, 0.923218591062165, 1.05479671552655, 1.00735000755924, 
1.27589740288217, 1.02161542258224, 1.02942019264802, 1.11220562520372, 
1.2503172434306, 1.06543554220541, 1.03225509167438, 1.12162389770652, 
0.938171644990446, 3.83059077421095, 3.53430087590307, 5.19114316091157, 
2.44226830818484, 2.11804166276486, 2.09764594188489, 2.7421494913755, 
2.40814336578664, 2.47217870956726, 2.07693755557431, 2.40579610247582, 
4.51572120035744, 2.23381805679009, 2.18769695837905, 2.50842606414176, 
2.31325007831315, 2.53903745425491, 2.78069481224444, 2.61233734268794, 
2.6021842042351, 2.31984775130926, 2.33324730169563, 2.57021891200676, 
2.85275081087314, 2.23768765525435, 1.86809140432887, 1.63849939440485, 
1.76660939882566, 1.88233589449823, 1.09197215977324, 1.04488408269238, 
1.00824446785133, 1.12956085472994), eogdp = c(84.0797988903791, 
84.7357174021739, 86.1164246868585, 85.828478200014, 84.4530242088487, 
83.7993941662979, 84.0513136270814, 84.3940307259146, 82.9967715042249, 
83.8847979117728, 82.5463415257105, 82.5548237917295, 82.5383437978321, 
79.1813103098019, 78.3743963329786, 79.3936602664222, 79.5886437642585, 
79.4609936786088, 78.0888205247364, 80.0149436310746, 82.1876958484553, 
83.7118543839729, 84.7043415259433, 80.6168363214478, 81.4860071900171, 
81.9532609894997, 80.0643083492295, 80.3550608990707, 78.6117508961537, 
81.2342893046697, 80.484847474023, 80.1334803868627, 80.7322331634588, 
81.7161058638331, 83.2106639117876, 83.6506951563877, 84.1941685842316, 
82.6736033792857, 81.3777076796591, 81.3813154989816, 81.6877085877086, 
82.3253224359182, 81.4087512020457, 82.6789187756725, 81.6564749963559, 
79.5989198633945, 76.283679931228, 75.5197578840959, 80.5430775293631, 
79.7934517672947, 83.2993369916939, 81.2476040914058, 81.470570622668, 
80.8275500763593, 80.057985195925, 81.2870470996371, 79.5422262634436, 
77.6558249540776, 81.0105947991367, 80.5135178177962, 79.9262751478809, 
80.2403234340501, 80.2307065919633, 79.7201530210364, 79.805255070774, 
79.8780104485585, 72.8159081274808, 70.7512307397225, 64.7043868164378, 
76.9661731126857, 77.6703244315425, 78.7349834416046, 78.6015841743396, 
80.4763100743126, 82.6555081011313, 86.0372309600922, 83.8327475755005, 
78.9017692214226, 83.2273022834506, 79.9540138658699, 80.9664110150353, 
80.8998339887965, 77.7523501385916, 81.140103897158, 81.369304818684, 
82.8643636271495, 85.2632426039584, 85.2357584439475, 86.1880199885128, 
83.3037198094136, 82.084248358954, 85.494837931748, 85.3378123795486, 
85.7316139181553, 86.0142892536045, 85.3501672774816, 82.5308700723425, 
83.6822485975814, 83.8012670512117), pgr = c(1.509110516, 1.6213902295, 
1.6840910467, 1.6816633881, 1.5869438622, 1.4360091106, 1.2508510172, 
1.1094188819, 1.078456365, 1.1952400662, 1.4004867984, 1.652058818, 
1.831424167, 1.8414430378, 1.6301663285, 1.2776218859, 0.8808217054, 
0.5535625205, 0.3413561827, 0.2951317175, 0.3702200047, 0.4789989929, 
0.5561328207, 0.6098892543, 0.6197244432, 0.6001328504, 0.5764594052, 
0.57280062, 0.5932969652, 0.6452466267, 0.7167856753, 0.7976599816, 
0.8628867461, 1.2532149586, 1.1227597999, 1.0161254853, 0.9552097325, 
0.9565979715, 1.0004015543, 1.0539528739, 1.0893653533, 1.1041073905, 
1.0880762788, 1.0485889347, 1.0072232606, 0.9680274351, 0.9150179132, 
0.8463611921, 0.7675877228, 0.6877818726, 0.6129743212, 0.5430073031, 
0.4806677607, 0.4272573231, 0.3676520016, 0.3153014652, 0.3006499971, 
0.3349077606, 0.4008131798, 0.4842668548, 0.5498157446, 0.5678559982, 
0.5194159042, 0.4242950221, 0.315027195, 0.2213209398, 2.2820293047, 
2.0814657296, 1.9548188026, 1.9790627141, 2.2029075379, 2.5442677753, 
2.8845436226, 3.1267852874, 3.2639875453, 3.2703938822, 3.1771131233, 
3.1328857964, 3.0841213228, 2.8530008352, 2.4061158751, 1.8571323685, 
1.1911778884, 0.6663059572, 0.6028947894, 1.1551422028, 2.0963008677, 
3.1527930213, 3.9267025032, 4.2163984719, 3.9174727146, 3.2595383154, 
2.5489099273, 1.9906218323, 1.5571124019, 1.3096761134, 1.1965670748, 
1.0934355495, 0.9579125335)), row.names = c("1-1985", "1-1986", 
"1-1987", "1-1988", "1-1989", "1-1990", "1-1991", "1-1992", "1-1993", 
"1-1994", "1-1995", "1-1996", "1-1997", "1-1998", "1-1999", "1-2000", 
"1-2001", "1-2002", "1-2003", "1-2004", "1-2005", "1-2006", "1-2007", 
"1-2008", "1-2009", "1-2010", "1-2011", "1-2012", "1-2013", "1-2014", 
"1-2015", "1-2016", "1-2017", "2-1985", "2-1986", "2-1987", "2-1988", 
"2-1989", "2-1990", "2-1991", "2-1992", "2-1993", "2-1994", "2-1995", 
"2-1996", "2-1997", "2-1998", "2-1999", "2-2000", "2-2001", "2-2002", 
"2-2003", "2-2004", "2-2005", "2-2006", "2-2007", "2-2008", "2-2009", 
"2-2010", "2-2011", "2-2012", "2-2013", "2-2014", "2-2015", "2-2016", 
"2-2017", "3-1985", "3-1986", "3-1987", "3-1988", "3-1989", "3-1990", 
"3-1991", "3-1992", "3-1993", "3-1994", "3-1995", "3-1996", "3-1997", 
"3-1998", "3-1999", "3-2000", "3-2001", "3-2002", "3-2003", "3-2004", 
"3-2005", "3-2006", "3-2007", "3-2008", "3-2009", "3-2010", "3-2011", 
"3-2012", "3-2013", "3-2014", "3-2015", "3-2016", "3-2017"), class = c("pdata.frame", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(list(ccode = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L), .Label = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", 
"1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-99L), class = c("pindex", "data.frame")))

INEQMF2 <- diff(log(ineq)) ~ diff(total) + diff(eogdp) 

SMINEQ2 <- pcce(INEQMF2, data = AT, model="p")
#> Error in solve.default(crossprod(tHhat), t(tHhat)): system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.12737e-31
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The `R` session information is as below:

```
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] car_3.0-8       carData_3.0-4   tseries_0.10-47 lmtest_0.9-37   zoo_1.8-8       readxl_1.3.1   
[7] plm_2.2-3       knitr_1.29      reprex_0.3.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] RcppParallel_5.0.2   StanHeaders_2.21.0-5 Formula_1.2-3        Rdpack_0.11-1       
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1     TTR_0.23-6           stats4_4.0.2         cellranger_1.1.0    
 [9] yaml_2.2.1           pillar_1.4.4         lattice_0.20-41      glue_1.4.1.9000     
[13] quadprog_1.5-8       digest_0.6.25        colorspace_1.4-1     sandwich_2.5-1      
[17] htmltools_0.5.0      clipr_0.7.0          pkgconfig_2.0.3      bibtex_0.4.2.2      
[21] rstan_2.19.3         haven_2.3.1          purrr_0.3.4          scales_1.1.1        
[25] processx_3.4.2       whisker_0.4          openxlsx_4.1.5       rio_0.5.16          
[29] tibble_3.0.1         generics_0.0.2       ggplot2_3.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.1      
[33] maxLik_1.3-8         cli_2.0.2            quantmod_0.4.17      magrittr_1.5        
[37] crayon_1.3.4         evaluate_0.14        ps_1.3.3             fs_1.4.2            
[41] fansi_0.4.1          nlme_3.1-148         MASS_7.3-51.6        forcats_0.5.0       
[45] xts_0.12-0.1         foreign_0.8-80       pkgbuild_1.0.8       loo_2.2.0           
[49] tools_4.0.2          data.table_1.12.8    prettyunits_1.1.1    hms_0.5.3           
[53] matrixStats_0.56.0   gbRd_0.4-11          lifecycle_0.2.0      stringr_1.4.0       
[57] munsell_0.5.0        zip_2.0.4            callr_3.4.3          compiler_4.0.2      
[61] rlang_0.4.7          grid_4.0.2           rstudioapi_0.11      miscTools_0.6-26    
[65] rmarkdown_2.3        gtable_0.3.0         inline_0.3.15        abind_1.4-5         
[69] curl_4.3             R6_2.4.1             gridExtra_2.3        dplyr_1.0.2         
[73] bdsmatrix_1.3-4      stringi_1.4.6        parallel_4.0.2       Rcpp_1.0.5          
[77] vctrs_0.3.4          tidyselect_1.1.0     xfun_0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

The total and eogdp variables are exactly collinear:

```
plot(ineq ~ total, data = AT[c("ineq", "total", 
                               "eogdp")] )
 plot(ineq ~ eogdp, data = AT[c("ineq", "total", 
                               "eogdp")] )
 plot(total ~ eogdp, data = AT[c("ineq", "total", 
                               "eogdp")] )
```

[image]

I'm guessing this was a made up dataset and you forgot to put in some random variation around the dependent variable? Just a guess. Either that or perhaps  you calculated eogdp from total or vice versa?

Comment: I calculated eogdp from total. In this case, what remedy can be employed; given that I ran the same equation on `rgg` and `hdi` as separate equations using the same `pcce` model without any error. Thank you for the prompt response. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what is intended. Since `eogdp` is exactly predictable from `total`, there should be no added information in a model to which either of them is added to the other. Perhaps you should mark this as answered and then take any further questions over to CrossValidated.com

Comment: Well noted. Thank you, much grateful.